# How to extract code on one DT-06 board to another board?

Tags: firmware

I have two DT-06 boards [DT06 datasheet](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/349564/UserManualForTTL-WiFi.pdf).

---

The board stock firmware provides Web UI for wifi/network/serial setup. I've replaced the firmware on one board with other sketch; but now I want to revert it to the stock firmware. I cannot find the stock firmware source code anywhere. The DT-06 manufacturer also won't give it out.

Is it possible to extract the stock firmware from another DT-06 board and put it back into the other DT-06 board?

Thank you.

Comment: why are you looking for the firmware source?

Comment: Have you tried finding the firmware in binary? That would be enough. Mostly firmware isn't opensource, but can be downloaded as hex file.

Comment: It could be either binary or source. I can't find both. Can I extract its binary from one of my  DT-06?

Comment: Did you copy from one DT-06 to another DT-06 with the above program? I would also like you to show me the connections. Thanks.

Comment: Just save the stock firmware from one DT-06 on your pc/laptop and flash the saved firmware to another DT-06 which stock firmware was replaced earlier See my commands in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I found a way to extract the binary file (stock firmware) from one DT-06 and flash it to another modified DT-06, by using esptool command

```
/*To extract firmware */:
esptool.py -p COM4 -b 460800 read_flash 0 0x400000 dt06_backup.bin
/*To flash the backup binary file to another DT-06 */
esptool.py -p com4 write_flash -fm dout 0x00000 dt06_backup.bin
```

Comment: I also have some DT-06 modules that did not come with the original firmware. I appreciate your knowledge. I'm just getting started with the arduino. It would be good for many if you could make the original firmware of the DT-06 Wifi module with the .ino extension as an arduino program.
, or you could send it. thank you: ferbela@freemail.hu

Comment: You may download its stock firmware (as a .bin file) from my google drive here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oJyDso02NVfE8YmhDvKFJmyJGmnOsdw2/view?usp=sharing
or as a zip file here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z19SgD2dpa5PM9bHKWDcOLvxZjFnL2d3/view?usp=sharing
I did not use Arduino software to extract its stock firmware. I use python commands as posted here. Sorry I'm not sure how to make it as xxx.ino as you suggested.